# Multiple CheckBoxLists using autopostback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have a project where I am taking multiple checkboxlists and totaling up points based on which boxes are checked in a certain list.  I then display the sum of these points to a text-box.  I do this for every checkboxlist.

The problem is this: when one checkboxlist gets changed, the other sums get removed from their respective text boxes.  I have attempted this both with read-only set to True (which is the ideal setting in my case) as well as set to False (as per [Problem in using AutoPostback in asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040905/problem-in-using-autopostback-in-asp-net-c-sharp))

Comment: set `autopostback = false` to your checkbox lists and calculate your sum using javascript and set the value of textbox.

Answer (score 0):

The script to use to apply the comment can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/vecalciskay/27uGQ/1/

hope it helps.